# Does the gravity model of trade apply equally for goods and services?

Tags: international-trade

Does the [gravity model of trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_model_of_trade) apply equally for goods and services?

Naively it would seem that the more ephemeral services would be less impacted by it?

Comment: Apply equally in what sense? Are the model parameters the same? Or allowing the parameters to vary, is the variation equally explained in services as in goods?

Comment: Neither (I think). I’d like to know whether there is a quantitative  difference in impact when the model is applied to each.

Comment: What do you mean by impact?

Comment: Effect on bilateral trade flows.